# SQL SUM (MIN(value) - MAX(value))

Tags: sql

I have a table containing EmployeeID and Weight.  I need to obtain MIN value and MAX value of column Weight and then calculate WeightLost as SUM(MIN - MAX).

Then finally new column WeightLostLBS = WeightLost * 2.2

```
employeeid    weight    
1             100
1             120
```

So result would be

```
EmployeeID    WeightLost    Min     Max   WeightLostLBS
1                20         100     120        44
```

Comment: `MIN()` and `MAX()` already aggregate across a group. That means they produce a single value per group each. You can subtract one from the other and you'll obtain a *single* value per group. What, then, is to be gained by wanting to run a further aggregate across that single value?

Comment: Why would you assume that the first weight is the highest and the last weight is the lowest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
       MAX(Weight) - MIN(Weight) AS WeightLost, 
       MIN(Weight) AS MIN, 
       MAX(Weight) AS MAX, 
       (MAX(Weight) - MIN(Weight))*2.2 AS WeightLostLBS
FROM table1
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

**Output**

```
EmployeeID  WeightLost  MIN   MAX   WeightLostLBS
1           20          100   120   44
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61b2c4/1

Answer (score 4):

You don't need sum here. Normal subtraction will work.

```
select EmployeeID, MAX(Weight) - MIN(Weight) as WeightLost, MIN(Weight), MAX(Weight), (MAX(Weight) - MIN(Weight))*2.2 as WeightLostLBS
from table
group by EmployeeID
```